# Adding a syntax group to support fold markers with foldmethod=syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding

With `foldmethod=syntax`, is it possible to create a syntax group that matches my fold markers, so that i can use *both* language-specific syntax folding and whatever markers might already be in my code?

I tried

```
syntax region MarkerFold start=/\V{{{/ end=/\V}}}/ fold transparent
```

But this won't work if there is already a matching syntax highlighting group. The problem still happens if I omit the `transparent` option.

Am I asking for the impossible? Or is there some way to achieve this in a language-agnostic way (i.e. not writing `contains=` with every possible vim filetype).

Edit with a Python example:

```
# Section of Code {{{             <-  Fold at marker
def func1(x):                     <-  Fold at syntax (function def)
    """ This is the docstring     <-  Fold at syntax (docstring)

    Here is documentation.
    More docs.
    """
    print('This is func1')
    return x+1
# }}}
```

Comment: *maybe* with a custom fold expression that tests for markers and syntax-fold elements?

Comment: Does [`transparent`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-transparent) work here? The example under [`:help :syn-fold`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-fold) uses it too... But yeah, syntax rules can be tricky, there's often too much interference when you try to add or remove something, so it's not always easy to add a single rule and keep everything else working as it did before the addition.

Comment: @filbranden I tried `transparent` and it has the same result.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble how would I implement such a thing, without reimplementing Vim's entire syntax folding mechanism in Vimscript? Or is it not so complicated to do?

Comment: I'm not certain you can avoid it, and I have no idea how complex it is. There are some syntax functions that would let you extract the info (I hope), and the algorithm is "simple" (`:help :syn-fold`, `:help fold-syntax`, `:help syntax-functions`)